# Find all non-overlapping intervals in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a nested list (already sorted with key being start element) defined as;

```
L=[[0,3],[1,2],[4,5],[6]]
```

The goal is to obtain tuples of all non-overlapping subintervals. Hence the output should look like;

```
[([0,3],[4,5],[6]),([1,2],[4,5],[6])]
```

I was able to do pairwise comparison with consecutive elements using following code;

```
overlap=False
Lnew=[]
for i in range(len(L)-1):
   overlap=False
   if L[i+1][0]<L[i][1]:
      overlap=True
   if overlap==False:
       Lnew.append((L[i],L[i+1]))
```

This idea gave me the following output;

```
[([1, 2], [4, 5]), ([4, 5], [6])]
```

As seen, it gives me a pair each time, which is not same as desired output. Can I get some help on how to modify my logic to obtain desired output? Kindly note that it needs to be done in linear time. That will b really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: How do you feel about *recursion*?  :)

Comment: thanks for the advice. Honestly, I'm not very sure on how to implement recursion for this problem. If you have some ideas, I'll gladly try it.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive idea here is that any time you find an overlapped interval, you have a new starting point.  That is the essence of recursion....  the big problem is covered by sub-problems of the same description, with logical stopping points.

Here the stopping points are getting to the last element with a solution in-hand and all sub problems solved.

```
# recursive non-overlapping interval finder
data = [[0,3],[1,2],[4,5],[6]]
data2 = [[0,5],[4,8],[7,15]]


def search( x: list,
            result: list) -> list:
    # stopping condition #1 ... last element was overlapped and is a singleton
    if len(x) == 1:
        result.append(tuple([x[0]]))
        return result
    temp = [x[0]]  # to hold intermediate result, starting with first input element
    for idx, element in enumerate(x[1:], 1):
        if element[0] >= temp[-1][1]:
            temp.append(element)
        else:  # found a new starting point
            search(x[idx:], result)
    result.append(tuple(temp))
    return(result)

print(f'\nsearching {data}')
res = search(data, [])
for t in res:
    print(t)

print(f'\nsearching {data2}')
res = search(data2, [])
for t in res:
    print(t)
```

### output

```
searching [[0, 3], [1, 2], [4, 5], [6]]
([1, 2], [4, 5], [6])
([0, 3], [4, 5], [6])

searching [[0, 5], [4, 8], [7, 15]]
([7, 15],)
([4, 8],)
([0, 5], [7, 15])
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Comment: I ran the code. it works fine.but it seems the stopping condition of checking length=1 is not being met. May I know-how is the code stopping?Do we really need the stopping condition for length=1 check?thanks

Comment: Oops.  You are correct.  The additional check for a singleton isn't necessary.  If it gets a singleton the for-loop doesn't execute, so it gets right to the return statement.  Do you understand the internal recursive call and that it will go to a stop and then the outer call of the function will then continue?

Comment: I do get most of the code. Just one clarification I need. Suppose we run code for ```[[0, 3], [1, 2], [4, 5], [6]]```, then for ```idx=1``` since there is overlap, the function calls itself recursively. Once the execution is over, the control goes back to recursive call, at that time ```x=[[1, 2], [4, 5], [6]]``` , ```idx=1``` and ```temp=[0,3]```, and ```res=[[1,2],[4,5],[6]]``` Am I correct in my understanding? Kindly let m know if I'm missing sth.

Comment: You got it.!  You can decorate it with a few print statements if you want to see the flow, but that is it.